# How to deserialize child nodes of xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've created an app using Xamarin Android. Plan is for it to open a read-only copy of Clients.xml from the Assets folder and create a copy in internal storage for future editing. The default file has a root node of clients and half a dozen child nodes of client.

I've got it to the point where it reads the asset and creates a local file but only with the first child node in it. I can't quite get it to an array of child nodes.

What do I need to do to read all the child nodes?

Reading of the asset and creating a local file.

```
        // Get storage path
        path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        // Create clients file on first build
        string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Clients.xml");
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            clients clients;

            // Load read-only asset from file
            var xmlSerialSettings = new XmlSerializer(typeof(clients));
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open("Clients.xml"), true))
            {
                clients = (clients)xmlSerialSettings.Deserialize(sr);
            }
            // Save local version to edit
            var xsw = new XmlSerializer(typeof(clients));
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
            {
                xsw.Serialize(sw, clients);
            }
        }
```

Clients.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<clients>
    <client id="1">
        <name>Bob</name>
        <address>Home</address>
        <postcode>CO1</postcode>
        <email>bob@home.com</email>
        <landline></landline>
        <mobile>07784</mobile>
    </client>
    <client id="2">
        <name>...</name>
        <address>...</address>
        <postcode>...</postcode>
        <email>...</email>
        <landline>...</landline>
        <mobile>...</mobile>
    </client>
    ....
</clients>
```

Clients.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace QuoteBuilder
{
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("clients")]
    public class clients
    {
        [XmlElement("client")]
        public client client { get; set; }

        public clients()
        {

        }

        public clients(client client)
        {
            this.client = client;
        }
    }

    public class client
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string landline { get; set; }
        public string mobile { get; set; }

        public client()
        {

        }

        public client(string name, string address, string postcode, string email, string landline, string mobile)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.postcode = postcode;
            this.email = email;
            this.landline = landline;
            this.mobile = mobile;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your clients class you defined a member - client. It is not a collection, and when you deserialize xml file to clients class it deserialize only one node (first).
Use List or other collections inside:

```
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("clients")]
    public class Clients
    {
        [XmlElement("client")]
        public List<Client> client { get; set; } // Collection

        public Clients()
        {

        }

        public Clients(List<Client> client)
        {
            this.client = client;
        }
    }
```

Also use CamelCase naming for classes, and lowerCase naming for variables - it is more readable

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'd been trying to use client[] but it was changing to the list which fixed it.